# ScriptRunConfig failing with exit code: 1

Tags: azure, jobs, azure-machine-learning-service

The same environment is used for my pipeline steps and they are running fine but the Script Run Config fails every time with same error. We are using the SDK v1.

"Creating conda environment failed with exit code: 1"

Python version used- 3.8 added as dependency while making the environment.

Code sample:
[enter image description here][1]

```
Output log: Streaming azureml-logs/60_control_log.txt
=========================================

[2023-02-08T22:03:43.622773] Using urllib.request Python 3.0 or later
Streaming log file azureml-logs/60_control_log.txt
Running: ['/bin/bash', '/tmp/azureml_runs/score_test/azureml-environment-setup/conda_env_checker.sh']
Starting the daemon thread to refresh tokens in background for process with pid = 12605
Materialized conda environment not found on target: /home/azureuser/.azureml/envs/azureml


[2023-02-08T22:03:43.744540] Logging experiment preparation status in history service.
Running: ['/bin/bash', '/tmp/azureml_runs/score_test/azureml-environment-setup/conda_env_builder.sh']
Running: ['conda', '--version']
conda 4.10.3

Creating conda environment...
Running: ['conda', 'env', 'create', '-p', '/home/azureuser/.azureml/envs/azureml', '-f', 'azureml-environment-setup/mutated_conda_dependencies.yml']
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.10.3
  latest version: 23.1.0

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda



Downloading and Extracting Packages
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(143): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/libffi-3.3-he6710b0_2/info/test/run_test.sh.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(143): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/libffi-3.3-he6710b0_2/info/recipe/patches/0001-check-for-existence-of-type-before-setting.patch.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(143): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/libffi-3.3-he6710b0_2/info/recipe/conda_build_config.yaml.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(143): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/libffi-3.3-he6710b0_2/info/recipe/configure_includedir_option.patch.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(143): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/libffi-3.3-he6710b0_2/info/recipe/meta.yaml.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(143): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/libffi-3.3-he6710b0_2/info/recipe/meta.yaml.template.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(143): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/libffi-3.3-he6710b0_2/info/recipe/recipe_log.txt.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(143): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/libffi-3.3-he6710b0_2/info/recipe/build.sh.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(143): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/libffi-3.3-he6710b0_2/info/run_exports.json.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(143): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/libffi-3.3-he6710b0_2/info/index.json.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(143): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/libffi-3.3-he6710b0_2/info/repodata_record.json.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
Show More...

TypeError('not all arguments converted during string formatting')
TypeError('not all arguments converted during string formatting')



Attempting to clean up partially built conda environment: /home/azureuser/.azureml/envs/azureml



Creating conda environment failed with exit code: 1



[2023-02-08T22:04:05.439184] Logging error in history service: Failed to run ['/bin/bash', '/tmp/azureml_runs/score_test_/azureml-environment-setup/conda_env_builder.sh'] 
 Exit code 1 
Details can be found in azureml-logs/60_control_log.txt log file.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ActivityFailedException                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-127-bc407f33209f> in <module>
      2 score_run = score_exp.submit(score_config)
      3 print(score_run)
----> 4 score_run.wait_for_completion(show_output=True)

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/core/run.py in wait_for_completion(self, show_output, wait_post_processing, raise_on_error)
    810                     file_handle=sys.stdout,
    811                     wait_post_processing=wait_post_processing,
--> 812                     raise_on_error=raise_on_error)
    813                 return self.get_details()
    814             except KeyboardInterrupt:

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/core/run.py in _stream_run_output(self, file_handle, wait_post_processing, raise_on_error)
   1052                 file_handle.write("\n")
   1053             else:
-> 1054                 raise ActivityFailedException(error_details=json.dumps(error, indent=4))
   1055 
   1056         file_handle.write("\n")

ActivityFailedException: ActivityFailedException:
    Message: Activity Failed:
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UserError",
        "message": "Creating conda environment failed with exit code: 1",
        "messageParameters": {},
        "details": []
    },
    "time": "2023-02-08T22:04:05.33789Z"
}
    InnerException None
    ErrorResponse 
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Activity Failed:\n{\n    \"error\": {\n        \"code\": \"UserError\",\n        \"message\": \"Creating conda environment failed with exit code: 1\",\n        \"messageParameters\": {},\n        \"details\": []\n    },\n    \"time\": \"2023-02-08T22:04:05.33789Z\"\n}"
    }
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZ40g.png
```

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to update the conda to the latest version by running the following command:

```
conda update -n base -c defaults conda
```

It is also recommended to remove the file "/anaconda/pkgs/libffi-3.3-he6710b0_2/info/test/run_test.sh" manually or by rebooting the system.